# Why in two floated divs just the content is wrapped?

Tags: html, css

I am really trying to learn how float works in CSS, and I am having lots of difficulties. The more I experiment, the more confused I get.  Check out this example:

```
<div class = "block1">hola</div>
<div class = "block2">hola</div>

.block1 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
    height:400px;
}

.block2 {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrNYR/3/)

Why the second block content gets side by side of the first block, but the container itself is right under the first block and expanding to the right?

This just happens if the width of the second block is bigger. If not, the second block just goes under. Why does that happen? Why not all the second block goes side by side of the first one, but it goes under?

Answer (score 1):

First, When you `float` any element it is taken out of the "normal flow" of the document. Second, It is considered good to always set width on a floated element. I am really bad at explaining.

[Read this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)

[And this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/)

Comment: @HommerSmith: Saying that it is not true is not right. Saying that it is debateable is more precise. In acutality and it amazed me also, when you float an element, the UA actually "ADDS A MARGIN" to it. Strange but true.

Answer (score 1):

these might help you...

[W3C - Visual formatting model - Positioning the float: the 'float' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float)

[W3C - Generic containers - the div and span elements](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements)